# I cannot understand function comparisons in Python

Tags: python, function, comparison

I am using the Canopy IDE. I am a beginner in Python. I was taking the edX online course where I stumbled upon this code:

```
def a(x,y,z):
    if x:
       return y
    else:
       return z
def b(p,r):
    return a(p>r,p,r)
print a(3>2,a,b)
```

I cannot understand how the statement `a(3>2,a,b)` works. In essence, how function comparison works in python. When I executed the code in my IDE, it gave the following output.

```
<function a at 0x00000000088F4198>
```

Comment: But that code is not supposed to be comparing functions. It's comparing values, as you can see in `b`. Why are you passing `a` as a parameter to itself?

Comment: p>r, respectively 3>2 return a boolean value

Comment: In python, anything are objects, including class, function, and so on. `a`, `b` are two function objects, and _0x00000000088F4198_ is function address You can `print a(3>2,a,b)(1, 2, 3)` to call method `a`.

Comment: i don't understand. what happens when we pass function names as parameters?

Comment: Note that the code you posted didn't pass function **name**, but a pointer to the function. When you pass a function as parameter, pointer to that function is being actually passed. Then it can be called just as the original function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call:

```
a(3>2, a, b)
```

Resulted in parameter 'a' being returned. Parameter a is the function used to perform comparison:

```
def a(x,y,z):
    if x:
       return y
    else:
       return z
```

Default string representation of a function is:

```
<function (name) at 0x(address in memory)>
```

Try running function a() with different arguments, like

```
 a(3>2, "Greater", "Smaller")
```

Or use Python ternary operator:

```
result = "Greater" if 3 > 2 else "Smaller"
```

Comment: but, another question. how to determine which function 'object' is greater?

Comment: I'd wager that this depends on Python implementation details. In CPython it seems that addresses are compared, so generally (in one module) function defined later is greater than function defined earlier. But WHY would you EVER need to check it? And what for? What would you like to achieve with your code?

Comment: Maybe you should check: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers ?